# How to access index.html page when I use http-server for NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, httpserver

I tried to use http-server for Nodejs so I followed the step from here.
[URL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

Once I start the server, it runs well but I cannot access the index.html page. The browser just show "This page isn’t working" message.

I am trying to use Angular's service worker and I tried to use this command.

> "C:\Works\angular-pwa-app\dist>http-server -c-1 ."

and

I could see:

> Starting up http-server, serving . Available on:
>   http://192.168.1.37:8080   http://127.0.0.1:8080 Hit CTRL-C to stop
>   the server

When I tried to access "http://127.0.0.1:8080", the command line shows:

> [Mon Jun 10 2019 14:38:23 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)] "GET /"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36"

and then I see the fail message on browser.

what did I miss?

Comment: Please share your project structure, is there public folder in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had problem running PWA from http server in my angular 7 application.

Than i switched to angular-http-server. It works perfectly with that--

You can find it in this link--

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-server

also you are running your http-server inside dist folder. It should be

> dist/your-project-name

folder if you are using version above 6.0 in angular. For version below 6 you can run the server from dist folder

For http-server with angular 7 and angular 8 you need to enable cliend side routing and that can be done with # routing --

> Try imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],

in your routing module. This normally solves http-server problem